# Filter an array with another array INCLUSIVELY

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having a hard time filtering an array by matching with all elements of another array,  INCLUSIVELY. So for example:

```
var s = [
 {id: 1, area: ['foo', 'bar', 'other', 'again']},
 {id: 2, area: ['bar']},
 {id: 3, area: ['other']},
 {id: 4, area: ['foo']}
]

var areas = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Expected output should be:

```
[
 {id: 1, area: ['foo', 'bar', 'other', 'again']}
]
```

that is, each element in the expected result must contain ALL elements in the 'areas' array.
This is what i tried but its returning an empty array so I think my function is wrong:

```
const filteredArray = s.filter(n => n.area.every(a => areas.includes(a)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check that each element from `areas` is present in `area` field. In your example, you are doing the opposite, trying to check that each `area` field is present in `areas`.

```js
const s = [
    { id: 1, area: ['foo', 'bar', 'other', 'again'] },
    { id: 2, area: ['bar'] },
    { id: 3, area: ['other'] },
    { id: 4, area: ['foo'] },
];
const areas = ['foo', 'bar'];

const result = s.filter(n => areas.every(a => n.area.includes(a)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks very much. That works for that array. but i just realized my array was slightly differently structured... The array area in s should actually be an array of objects like this: s = [
    { id: 1, area: [{area: 'foo'}, {area: 'bar}', {area: 'other}', {area: 'again'}] },
    { id: 2, area: [{area: 'bar}'] },
    { id: 3, area: [{area: 'other'}] },
    { id: 4, area: [{area: 'foo'}] },
];
how would the function be in this case?

Comment: @Diego Try it `s.filter(obj => areas.every(filterArea => obj.area.map(areaObj => areaObj.area).includes(filterArea)));`